# Big-O division in $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ of Taylor polynomials

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

[Here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor.pdf) p.4 bottom is a proof that proves a property of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, the quotient of two Taylor polynomials of f and g.

For two Taylor polynomials of $f(x) = \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x^k}{k!}+o(x^k)$ and $g(x) = \frac{g^{(k)}(x_0)x^k}{k!}+o(x^k)$ :

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)+o(1)}{g^{(k)}(x_0)+o(1)}$$

What I'm trying to understand is how does the cancellation of the $o(x^k)$ terms work out to $o(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $F(x) = o(x^k)$ as $x \to 0$, then
$$ \frac{F(x)}{x^k} \to 0  \quad \text{ as } x \to 0 $$
But this is the same as saying
$$ \frac{x^{-k}F(x)}{1} \to 0 \quad \text{ as } x \to 0, $$
i.e. $ x^{-k}F(x) = o(1) $ as $x \to 0$. Therefore, as sets,
$$ x^{-k}o(x^k) = o(1) $$
This means that dividing numerator and denominator of the fraction by $x^k$ gives the expression on the right.